# how to create a script to check a list of users present in a system

Tags: linux, bash, performance, shell

I have a list of users in a file ( America, Belgium, India, Srilanka, Bhutan)
I need to run a script on each machine to check the above users exist, if its does not, create those users,
users are on file resides in `/etc/users.txt`

Contents of `users.txt`

```
America
Belgium
India
Srilanka
Bhutan
```

I tried this, but it's not checking users on my list of files.

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -q "^$1:" /etc/users.txt ;then
    echo exists
else
    echo FALSE
fi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. Show (a few lines of) the contents of `/etc/users`. How exactly do you run your script? What command line argument(s) do you use? What is the output you get and what do you expect instead.

Comment: You didn't show how you invoke the script. Also, why do you tag this _bash_, if you seemingly want to write a _sh_ script. May I suggest removing the _bash_ tag? The _performance_ tag also doesn't seem to make sense IMO.

Comment: `grep /etc/users` will not look at the file `/etc/users.txt`.  Is that a typo in the question, or do you expect a magical path expansion to add the extension?

Comment: The content of the file you show does not contain `:`.  If you fix the invocation of `grep` to look at that file, it will not match any lines since they do not contain `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you didnt call users.txt, you just called users
2. you have a bunch of incorrect regex in your grep
3. (optional) you should use -i on grep to accept lowercase letters

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   if grep -i -q "$1" /etc/users.txt ;then
      echo exists
   else
      echo FALSE
   fi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop to read from file:

```
while read -r line;
do
if id "$line" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$line exists"
else
        echo "$line does not exist"
        sudo useradd "$line"
fi 
done < file
```